# How to determine which ruby gem version is actually in use

Tags: heroku, rack, unicorn

I'm doing some load testing with Unicorn on Heroku Celadon Cedar stack and I need to know which version of unicorn I used. I just included `gem 'unicorn'` in the `Gemfile`.

Is there anyway of knowing the unicorn version number?

**EDIT**

I'm using JRuby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
bundle list | grep unicorn
```

and it will show the gem version number.

Comment: I'm currently using JRuby and I get 'Your Ruby engine is ruby, but your Gemfile specified jruby'. Added EDIT

Comment: Worked around the prob. Thanks :)